# How can i change comment form in drupal 6?

Tags: comments

I just want to change comment form completely not in css in html/php like change title name comments to mycomment and post your comment to create a comment etc...

and i also want this only for particular page like i want for contact us page comments to Your Details and for about us page write your suggestion.

plz help me..